# What is the best table plugin for react ? like we have DataTable in jquery

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I am working on react application and I want all features for tables implementation that jquery Datatable offer.

Comment: Don't mind! but you can get this answer by simple google search

Comment: You can actually use the JQuery datatables within a React App.  It takes a little bit of extra thinking to manage data updates\state updates and ultimately table updates, but is completely possible.  I have a couple of apps in Production that are React based and use datatables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try:[`react-table`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table). It has common features as Datatable. You can take a look at there examples at https://reactjsexample.com/tag/table/

Answer (score 1):

try react-bootstrap-table, I'm using it in a production project and so far don't have any major complaints

Comment: is react-bootstrap-table have all features that jquery DataTable have ?